# Need a specific image viewer

Tags: arch-linux, image-viewer

After I create a folder with all the pictures I took I always have the same workflow: I enter the slideshow mode then for each picture I either remove, crop/rotate or do nothing.

On Windows it is a breeze through [Microsoft Photos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Photos) but I can't find any viewer/editor for my computer running Arch Linux. Basically I only need these features available during slideshow:

- arbitrary rotation
- cropping
- removal

Is there any software like this?

I tried eog but it doesn't include any editor feature, and then Shotwell but I cannot remove an image during slideshow.

Comment: Seems it's been nearly 10 years since this feature is wanted for shotwell..! https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=716339

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by "arbitrary rotation", it sounds like gwenview would meet your needs. gwenview is a KDE desktop component; I do not know how much of the KDE desktop you would have to install in order to run it.

Comment: I often need to rotate 1 or 2 degrees but most image viewers only allow increments of 90 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine a viewer with a separate editor. For example, `gimp` is a well-known editor that can do a lot of sophisticated operations, so it can be difficult to learn. However, it might be easy enough to master rotate and clip, using single-window-mode to keep everything visible, and not quitting it after closing an image, to reduce start-up time.

A viewer like `feh` is a lightweight viewer that allows you to delete files, and you can configure an action to run `gimp` on the currently shown image (for example, `feh --action1 'gimp %f &'` then press `1` to run `gimp`).  If you prefer more of a *gui*, `ristretto` has a more user-friendly appearance, can delete images (by moving them to `~/.local/share/Trash/`), and has an Edit button that can be set to run *GNU Image Manipulation Program* (i.e. `gimp`) on the image.

Comment: Thanks but I'd rather not switch between different softwares.

Answer (score 0):

Try XnViewMP, free for personal use: https://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/#downloads

I've only used it on Windows but they do have a Linux build as well. Never used MS Photos so can't compare the two.

XnViewMP allows deleting during slideshows, has fine rotation, and has cropping.

Unfortunately, rotation and cropping are batch operations so they aren't that quick to set up and use during a slideshow.

Comment: Hm thanks but I just tried and I didn't see any control besides previous/next picture =/

Answer (score 0):

Try nomacs. It supports rotating in single degree increments as well as cropping while functioning primarily as a viewer.